# Integrating R outputs in bsplus functions

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I consider `bsplus` package as relevant when developing dynamic webs. I use R Markdown in Rstudio.

However, I find particularly tricky the way to integrate `bsplus` functions with R outputs.

Let's see an example with the `bs_accordion` function, using `mtcars` dataset

```
head <- head(mtcars)
tail <- tail(mtcars)

bs_accordion(id ="Data: mtcars") %>%
  bs_append(title = "Head of mtcars", content = head) %>%
  bs_append(title = "Tail of mtcars", content = tail)
```

I would like to display R outputs in the accordion function, displaying the data frames `head` and `tail`.

Now, it only displays the first numerical row in the `head`.

Is there any possibility to include R code within the `content` attribute in the `bsplus` functions?

In this way we could be able to display R results in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your example. You have to create a datatable somehow, just including it wont render it as a table.

Note: I changed the id of the accordion to `Data-mtcars`. Using a whitespace, ":" or ";" will disable the collapsing.

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  bs_accordion(id ="Data-mtcars") %>%
    bs_set_opts(panel_type = "primary", use_heading_link = T) %>%
    bs_append(title = "Head of mtcars", content = DT::dataTableOutput("table1")) %>%

    bs_set_opts(panel_type = "primary", use_heading_link = T) %>%
    bs_append(title = "Tail of mtcars", content = DT::dataTableOutput("table2"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    head
  })  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    tail
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```